# Return value in login_form not working

Tags: expressionengine

I have a login form at the following page:

**site.com/en/downloads**

“en” is the user_language ( and is stored as such in a global var )

when I login, the form redirects me to:

**site.com/downloads**

While it should redirect me to the URL with my user_language

I’ve tried numerous things, but the value of **the return value always gets ignored.**

- return =”{site_url}/{user_language}/downloads”
- return =”{site_url}”
- return =“http://site.com”
- return =“http://google.com”
- return =“about/index”

they all redirect to site.com/downloads.

the code that is being outputted ( for the last example ) looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://site.com/"  >
<div class='hiddenFields'>
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="9fae3b1b5fcf882776da6638706595af73a7b15d" />
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="7" />
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="about/index" />
<input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
</div>
```

I have an .htaccess that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I tried using freemember as suggested, but the problem remains the same:

**I've set the return value to "about/index", but I'm still being redirected to site.com/downloads.**

The code generated by freemember looks solid though, so something must be overriding the return value.

```
<form method="post" action="http://site.com/downloads"  >
<div class='hiddenFields'>
<input type="hidden" name="XID" value="d9483688fbf63d9ea47e89a66e074b99f5b8465c" />
<input type="hidden" name="ACT" value="18" />
<input type="hidden" name="_params" value="wvkEsN96mPfmlhgerM2ppxGbMmiLJrz0Ntn7apKer/rmBpQaUozvSM0TvkVN66QlX/ptCM1IQGsuZuw7X3mzlOMCFIUyYFpbZy5h7nfPJMiHLdpqXqwBFOiA/zcNW0GKAIicv4JPAS2mfHKQE+mb2Ct0L+jhGz0NlSdELuMOeqQPJJ3B7U90D5w/sKTeaX5zaOMSvKJ4LZ7xP0Dn+UxE9g==" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="about/index" />
<input type="hidden" name="site_id" value="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the version of EE you're using as well? If it's a bug it'd be good to know which version it's happening in.

Comment: Oh, and maybe try to show your entire template code where this form lies? There may be some other code conflict that's happening in the template that's forcing a redirect.

Comment: You haven't got anything in your template preferences that is setting the redirect have you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

Apparently I was still using a small plugin called "Twomile Login Redirect" which hijacked my login code ( even when it was disabled, I had to remove it )

So all is well now.

Lesson learned: remove old plugins :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `return="{user_language}/about/index"` parameter as you mentioned above, does it correctly output the `RET` variable in the HTML code? How about just adding your own `RET` hidden input field? Just put this inside your login form somewhere:

```
<input type="hidden" name="RET" value="{user_language}/about/index" />
```

According to the HTML spec, if two inputs have the same `name`, then the later one will override any previous ones, so there is no problem doing it this way.

Alternatively, you could try using the [Freemember](https://exp-resso.com/freemember) plugin - you might have more luck with the return URL, and you can avoid the nasty grey redirect pages as well. `</shameless-plug>`

Comment: Yes, it correctly outputs the RET variable. ( as you can see in the piece of code I posted: the RET value is about/index, as it should be, but it still redirects to my downloads/index )  I even tried manually setting the RET value, but even that is getting ignored.  I'll most definitely try out your plugin, can't wait to get rid of those redirect pages.

Comment: Hmm ok. If may be a bug in EE then. What about giving Freemember a go? UPDATE: Cool, let us know how you get on.

Comment: I will. Also, could you vote up my question ? I need some more rep before I can vote up your answer :)

Comment: Sure. I think you need to get to 15 rep before you can upvote - you're nearly there! You can also mark my answer as "accepted" if it helped you.

Comment: That's really strange. Are you sure there is nothing else in your htaccess file? Is your about/index template redirecting again for some reason? Finally, could you post a URL or screenshot of your Chrome/Firebug Network tab showing the redirects after you submit your login form?

Comment: nothing else in htaccess file => yep. about/index redirecting => no ( if I replace with site/index the result remains the same ). Firebug shows no redirects: http://cl.ly/image/0v323O1Y2Q22

Comment: Are you running MSM? What extensions do you have installed? One of them must be hijacking your login redirect, because what you're seeing makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

i might be looking at this to superficcially, but couldn't you use

```
return =”{segment_1}/downloads”
```

Comment: won't work: {segment_1} contains "downloads" the "en" is a global var. It also doesn't matter what I put in the return value at the moment, everything gets ignored.